# php detects types of content in Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like that my php detects seperatly images (media) and text, from a same wordpress post, in regard to display them in different columns. I am using Bootstrap, and I would like different display of each (text and image) according to the screen size. 
Here is a code I have that displays all of the content of my post (image and text) at once, it works perfectly :

```html
<div class="container">

 <?php if (have_posts()):  ?>
  
  <div class="container">
   <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">      
      <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
    </div>  

   <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div> 
  
 <?php endif; ?> 
  
</div>
```

I would like the same way of loading content but instead of having just

```html
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

I would like something like this to place text and image (of same post) in different div class:

```html
<?php the_image(); ?> 

AND

<?php the_text(); ?>
```

I know this is wrong code but I am trying to be clear in my explanation. I need that my client does not touch any of code, also shortcode in Wordpress post. Any input or advice would be very appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess that's what you want: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114477/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! Lars Beck, you solved my problem!
Here is the code I was looking for:

```html
<?php 
        //get content from back office , filter imgs except featured img to place them later in  <div id='img_content_right'>
                $content2 = get_the_content();                    
                $removed_imgs = array();                 
                $content2 = preg_replace_callback('#(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)(<img.+? />)#',function($r) {
                    global $removed_imgs;
                    $removed_imgs[] = $r[1];
                    return '';
                },$content2);

                    //add filter to the_content to strip images except img_menu et featured_img          
                    add_filter('the_content', 'strip_images',2);                    
                    function strip_images($content){            
                        $content=preg_replace('/(?!<img.+?id="img_menu".*?\/>)(?!<img.+?id="featured_img".*?\/>)<img.+?\/>/','',$content);                                  
                        return $content;                            
                    }

          the_content(); 
?>


  <div id='img_content_right'>
    <?php       
    //append the images stripped from content
     foreach($removed_imgs as $img){
                echo $img;
             }  
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way, to separate out images from the content section if they have just been included as part of the content.

Wordpress has featured image functionality built in for you. so you can use `the_post_thumbnail()` to echo out the image. Maybe this question can help you [Wordpress featured image code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050201/wordpress-featured-image-code)

If this isn't enough for you and you need more flexibility you might want to look at advanced custom fields plugin - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ it makes it easy for you to add your own fields of any type you want.

Comment: It can easily be done using a filter on `the_content`, see my comment

Comment: Ah, yeah that would work. I guess I was thinking of a slightly different use case, and the potential future issues with altering the post content before it is displayed. That would be really tough to figure out what was going on further down the line.

Comment: Filtering the content indeed is not very elegant but it works, so I'd absolutely agree with using ACF here